# JNI compiling fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, java-native-interface, g++

I'm working on a JNI lib for a i2c sensor and I can't get my makefile to work, can someone please take a look:

```
CC = gcc

#CFLAGS  = -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -marmv6z -Wall
CFLAGS  = -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -marm -O3 -Wall -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/linux
LIBS= -L'$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)' -ljvm
LD = ld
LDFLAGS =


OBJ = Test.o raspi.o i2c.o sht21.o
BIN = libpijava.so

gpio: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
        rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJ)
```

My JNI c file is Test.cpp, it is dependent on sht21.h, raspi.h and i2c.h

Changed too:

```
CC = gcc -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

#CFLAGS  = -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -marmv6z -Wall
CFLAGS  = -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -marm -O3 -Wall -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/linux
LD = ld
LDFLAGS =


OBJ = Test.o raspi.o i2c.o sht21.o
BIN = libpijava.so

gpio: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
        rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper include directory by passing the right `-I` flag to the C compiler.  The directory is very system-dependent.  On a Debian system, with an installed `default-jdk-headless` package, adding `-I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include` should work.

I think you will run into a linker failure for `-ljvm`.  You do not actually need to link against the JVM in this way for JNI libraries (only for applications which spawn a JVM).  If you actually need `-ljvm`, things are more complicated.  I don't think there is a fully portable path to it.  On my Debian system, it's `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so`, and even the path under the `default-java` directory contains an `amd64` reference, unfortunately.

Comment: I changed it too:
*posted in edit on question*
And it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, mistyped the path. You'll also have to install the `default-jdk-headless` package.

Comment: No can do, its a raspberry pi I'm running it on: package not found

Comment: The java paths are good I can manually compile it but I get link issues

Comment: As I said, for a JNI library, you don't actually have to link with `-ljvm` if you just want to create a JNI library.

Comment: I did remove that, heres what I get manually compiling http://i.imgur.com/qVKBLUM.png

Comment: That's a undefined reference to `GetRaspberryHwRevision`, and that does not come from the Java JDK, but some other library. This means you need to link against yet another library (or maybe you have missed to link in a file from your project).

Comment: Its from raspi.h